# what % of remaining of remaining coats are full length

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A garment supplier stores $800$ coats in a warehouse of which $15$% are full length coats.

If $500$ of shorter length coats are removed from warehouse what % of remaining of remaining coats are full length ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : $15% $ of $800$ is 120 . Now out of $800$ , we know $ 120$  are of full length coats

step 2 : if $500$ shorter once are removed from the total of $ 800 $ then left once are $300$
now of these $300$ we have 120 as full length and rest shorter once

Steo 3 : Calculate this % of full length from 300 left and it is $\frac {120}{300} \times 100 = 40$ %